# Dart / Flutter error: 'toStringDeep' isn't defined for the class 'Logger'

Tags: logging, dart, flutter

Aye aye good people,

after several runs of debugging, suddenly...
[logging](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/logging) suddenly return me this error:

> Compiler message: org-dartlang-debug:synthetic_debug_expression:1:1:
>   Error: Method not found: 'toStringDeep'. toStringDeep() ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   org-dartlang-debug:synthetic_debug_expression:1:1: Error: The method
>   'toStringDeep' isn't defined for the class 'Logger'.
>    - 'Logger' is from 'package:logging/logging.dart' ('file:///C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/logging-0.11.3+2/lib/logging.dart').

"toStringDeep" isn't my stuff, probably used in logging;
I tried to go back on my steps and remove the log(?) I've added,
but still returns the same error.

any help? pretty please...

Francesco

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When I get this error, I use "flutter clean" and it solves the problem.

Answer (score 16):

I ran into a similar issue, for me It only happens with Android Studio's interface run/debug button. It was working fine with `flutter run` command.

But clearing out the build files/cache fixed the issue.

## 1. Android Studio:

> Menu Tool > Flutter > Flutter Clean

## 2. OR run the command on CLI:

```
flutter clean
```

## 3. Using shortcut

It doesn't have a default key shortcut to run flutter clean, but you can add one easily.
I added <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> hotkey for `flutter clean`. You can define yours. Here is how:

1. Open Preferences/Settings.

[image]

2. Click on Keymap
3. Search for flutter clean.
4. Right click on `Flutter Clean` and select `Add Keyboard shortcut`

[image]

5. Add the keyboard short cut you prefer. I added `Command + H`

[image]

Now you can do it quicker.

Comment: works, as also Andre suggested, the absurd part is that I have to do it every time i run it :(
plus suddenly isn't showing the logs anymore :/

Comment: If you add a keyboard short cut for flutter clean, that would make it little easier to run, I just updated the answer with that.

Comment: I tried with only 1st Step and it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

alternatively, just remove the build folder.

Answer (score 3):

Running `flutter clean` in terminal solves this for me. Annoying bug that happens quite often right now.

Answer (score 1):

run in Terminal :

```
flutter clean
```