# The method 'toStringDeep' isn't defined for the class 'NumberFormat'

Tags: dart, flutter

My app was working perfectly and suddenly it started showing me compiler error. Here is the error:

```
Compiler message:
org-dartlang-debug:synthetic_debug_expression:1:1: Error: Method not found: 'toStringDeep'.
toStringDeep()
^^^^^^^^^^^^
org-dartlang-debug:synthetic_debug_expression:1:1: Error: The method 'toStringDeep' isn't defined for the class 'NumberFormat'.
 - 'NumberFormat' is from 'package:intl/intl.dart' ('file:///Users/chandra/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/intl-0.15.7/lib/intl.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toStringDeep'.
toStringDeep()
```

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55476240/dart-flutter-error-tostringdeep-isnt-defined-for-the-class-logger?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a hassle to do this every time so I saved it default config which works for any `Flutter` run.

1. `Run` --> `Edit Configurations`
2. Select `Flutter` and then add new configuration of external tool like
   [image: add external tool]
3. Next create tool as shown
   [image: step 3]
4. Make sure our external tool is checked
   [image: step 4]
5. Finally, you should have something like
   [image: step 5]
6. Hit ok and done!!!

Now every time you run a `Flutter` app, it will clean the build first.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known bug 36091](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36091) and [30381](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30381) which should be fixed in the next release. The only workaround is to run `flutter clean`. (Using Android Studios Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Clean should also work).

Comment: you mean, even after `flutter clean`? for me it then works for quite a while.. you can also try to upgrade the beta channel (which had a new release a few days ago) or the master channel. i haven't worked long enough yet with the beta channel to know if it still happens to me though.. so ymmv